# Why Angular 6 try to embed all HTML and CSS file into js file (main.js)?

Tags: javascript, angular, optimization, angular-cli, angular6

I recently working with Angular 6 and find out that *Angular CLI* embed all HTML and CSS file into a js file named `main.js`. I think it's not optimization, after a while you have a big `main.js` file.

In *angularjs* we had `ocLazy` that works very simple. I know that we have *Lazy* in angular 6 but this feature embed HTML and CSS files too.

**What is *PROS* and *CONS* of embedding all Controller + HTML + CSS file into a js file?**